# Improving tab view for knots

Tags: curated-data, gui-construction

This code:

```
TabView[Graphics[KnotData[#, "BraidDiagramData"], 
    Epilog -> 
     Inset[Style[KnotData[#, "AlexanderBriggsNotation"], 
       Large], {Right, Bottom}, {Right, Bottom}]] & /@ 
  Take[KnotData[All], {2, 6}], ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

will produce this tabbed view:

[image]

I have two questions:

*1. As you can see, in the bottom right part **of each knot's diagram**, Alexander-Brigs notation for the particular knot is displayed. I find that place a little bit annoying, it causes overlap between notation and braids. How can I move Alexander-Briggs notation to the bottom right **of correspondent tab page**?*

*2. How can I display some other property (number or string, let's say "BraidWordNotation" or "ConwayNotation") of knots within tab titles, instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 used it the picture above?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
TabView[KnotData[#, "BraidWordNotation"] -> 
    Labeled[Graphics[KnotData[#, "BraidDiagramData"]], 
     Style[KnotData[#, "AlexanderBriggsNotation"], 
      Large], {{Right, Bottom}}] & /@ Take[KnotData[All], {2, 6}], 
 ControlPlacement -> Left, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]